# typescriptでネストしたオブジェクトのundefinedチェック

Tags: typescript

以下のような`type`があるとします．

```
type Hoge {
  id: number,
  text?: string
}

type Fuga {
  hoge?: Hoge[]
}
```

このとき`undefined`チェックをしたいのですが，以下のようにしてもエラーが発生します．

```
const fuga: Fuga = {

  // properties

}

if(fuga.hoge !== undefined && fuga.hoge[0].text !== undefined){

  // some process

}
```

エラー内容：

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

主な環境は以下です．

```
dependencies:
  @types/node: ^12.12.17
  @types/react: ^16.9.16
  @types/react-dom: ^16.9.4
  @babel/core: ^7.7.5
  @babel/preset-env: ^7.7.6
  babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx: ^6.24.1

devDependencies:
  ts-loader: ^6.2.1
  typescript: ^3.7.3
```

何か解決策がありましたらよろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 質問に記載のコードだけではエラーは発生せず、当該エラーもts3.1+ではそうであってほしい挙動をしているようにみえますが…… https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gc2gXigbwFBSgSwCYBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0WUwEAHsAPxEDOwNOxCDAF8MGUJCgAxUggCGUVJmwALRBE6w1AbQC6w0QGM4xHlABmM2UWlyF6RqqREtafEQCMQvSIw4zUAAoLOQA6R2gAQmRUUmI8CDN+CDwoADJU80sw7QAGHRDmNigomLiEpLwASntsIxNgKCsoHj4BO2DZbKQtPILWYEY6rjgAGwgQkcQA2UrhIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hinaloeさん，コメントありがとうございます．
playground上で試してみましたが，確かにエラーが起きませんでした^^;
しかし，なぜだか僕のPC上ではエラーが起きてしまっていました．

一応，打開案を発見したので解答として載せます．

打開案としては，`!`(non-null assertion)をつける，もしくは無理やり`string`にキャストするというのが無難かと思いました．

原因ですが，おそらく`HTMLInputElement`を使用していたからではないかと思います．（`HTMLInputElement`のことを質問に載せてませんでした，すみません）
`querySelectorAll`で取ってきた`HTMLInputElement`の`value`プロパティに順次代入しようとしたところでエラーが起きたので，ちゃんと`null`チェックしろって怒られたのかと思うのですが，詳しいことはわかりませんでした．